# How can I minimize the object creation during Out of memory?

Tags: java, performance, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am facing Out of memory issue. Heap size is the problem. 
In the heap dumps I see many objects of CV.

Declaration:

```
private Map pVs = null;
```

Method used:

```
public void pV(AV value) {
    pVs.put(value.getName(), new CV(value));
}
```

Usage: (multiple places like this)

```
for (int i = 0; i < st.length; ++i) {
        d.pV(new VB(st.NAMES[i],
            st.H_STATUS, true, (status & mask) != 0, timestamp));
      }
```

How can I minimize the object creation? Is there anything I can do to optimize this?

Comment: The Method takes `AV` which is wrapped in `CV` and the caller actually creates a new `VB` ... I would suggest stepping back and have a look at your overall design.

Comment: Is this obfuscated code or did you choose the class and variable names on purpose?

Comment: @Henry..You are right. This is obfuscated code.

Comment: It will be harder to give you an answer if the code doesn't make any sense. Like why do you wrap a VB which is an AV in another CV, but its also a pV. Why not just put the AV in the map? The only answer we can give based on this code is that apparently you should instantiate less CV's. We cannot tell you how because you are not telling why you are instantiating CV's in the first place.